# Mediapipe Iris cannot detect face while wearing a mask

Tags: mediapipe

I made the program with mediapipe iris and it detects well

when there is an image with face not wearing a mask.

However, if I wear a mask and try to detect iris, it does not catch the either face or iris. Is there any solution for detecting iris when a person wearing a mask??

[image]

As you can see the picture, ABSCENT means couldn't detect the face and ATTEND means detected the face.

THOSE ABSCENT image files have faces wearing mask and ATTEND image files have faces not wearing mask

Comment: You have to detect them by their heart beat. That was the governments solution to this issue, anyway.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Thanks for your comment, but it wouldn't be the answer for my question...